# Android HTTP GET cookie / javascript issue?

Tags: javascript, android, cookies, httpclient, httprequest

I wrote an Android app that should 'connect' to a (private) forum using HTTP GET (and sometimes POST) requests. The basic idea is as such:

1. Login page where users submit their credentials. Login is performed by doing a HTTP POST (tried GET too, same result) to the Login page of the forum, with their username and password as the parameters. The request should return some cookies that I store in a `BasicCookieStore`.
2. Every page of the forum they want to visit is retrieved using HTTP GET. I parse the HTML source that I obtain and show them only the relevant info. In order to authenticate the users, the same `BasicCookieStore` that I used for login (step 1) is set as the cookiestore for the `HttpClient`.

This method has been working all the time during my testing, and has worked for my beta testers too. Now that I released the app, it became apparent that many users were having issues, especially on *mobile connections* (Wifi seems to be no problem).

By logging the HTML source that was returned in all the HTTP GET requests, I have a strong suspicion that the actual login works fine, but somehow the cookies don't get returned or stored or something in that direction. The problem is that the HTML source of the first page they will receive should be the list of forums. In the case of users with problems however, they get served a page that basically reads **"You must enable Javascript to view this page"**.

The strange thing is, I don't receive that page when testing, nor do many of my users. Even worse: some users are now reporting it worked fine for them for days or weeks, and has now stopped working. Others have the exact opposite: not working for days, suddenly working now. One user has reported he was in Greece for 2 weeks, where it worked flawlessly, then he got back to Germany, and it stopped working again.
There seems to be a random component at play here.

I have tried various things, mostly with the way I do the HTTP GET requests. I started out using the normal `DefaultHttpClient`, with various settings, such as this:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

// Define parameters
HttpParams httpParams = httpClient.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT); 
HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(httpParams, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

// Set cookiestore (getCookieStore returns the same cookiestore)
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, getCookieStore());

HttpGet http = new HttpGet(url);
http.addHeader("Accept", ACCEPT_STRING);
http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");

// Execute
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(http, localContext);
//... Process result (omitted)
```

Now I have switched to using AndroidHttpClient instead, with the rest of the code basically unchanged, and seem to get the same result.

I have also tried using the AsyncHttpClient library, which works quite differently, but once again the same result. I tried using its PersistentCookieStore as well, and you guessed it - same result.

I am clueless at this point. Am I looking in the wrong direction? The fact that a website would respond with "you need to enable Javascript" for some users but not for all seems to indicate an issue with cookies. I don't know how a website determines if javascript is enabled, but surely with a HTTP GET request there is no javascript at play. So why do I (and many other users) get to the page without any problems, while others get the 'no javascript' message? The only reason I can think of is cookies, but I have no clue what the problem exactly is.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the problem is cookies. More likely is a network configuration problem.

For example, your user might have connected to a wifi hotspot with a captive portal page (which uses javascript to make you sign in before you can use the hotspot). In this case they should first open the browser, try to browse to (e.g.) http://google.com, get redirected, sign in, and *then* launch your app.

Or, your user might be connecting through a proxy. Many mobile carriers around the world will proxy their users' HTTP connections, sometimes doing horrible things to the content. Switching to HTTPS might help with that.

Comment: Thanks. A Wifi hotspot seems unlikely seeing as they are mostly having problems during mobile connections (3G, 4G, etc). Your second suggestion could be the problem. How do I get around the proxy issues? Can I just replace 'http' with 'https' in the url even though the pages are normally accessed via http (with the login page being the only exception which is always https)?